# What are a00000 files and how to control them?

Tags: arcmap, file-geodatabase

Within my file geodatabase (ArcMap 10.6), I have probably thousands of files that begin with "a00000". Most of them are .gdbindexes, .gdbtable, .gdbtablex, .spx and the full name will be something like "a00000526".

What are these files and why are they being generated?

I'd like to know if I can delete them, and if I can tweak my file management to avoid having a bunch of unidentifiable files stored in my file geodatabase.

Comment: It would be unwise to delete any of those files, since you would be destroying the file geodatabase. Some are more critical than others, but removing any one would result in access failure to one of the tables.

Comment: "By design, it is difficult, if not impossible, to tell which files make up any given dataset." http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/file-geodatabases-and-windows-explorer.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although a file geodatabase is stored in a folder the contents of files in that folder are interpreted by products in the ArcGIS platform including the FileGDB API. If any are deleted then there is a high probability that your file geodatabase will become unusable.

To remove contents from a file geodatabase use only software which is designed to do that like ArcMap's Catalog window, ArcGIS Pro, tools from the ArcGIS Geoprocessing Framework, etc.